# Rectifier Bleed Off

Tags: power-supply, voltage

"Disclaimer I am a chemical engineer trying to tackle an electrical engineering issue we have". I have 5 rectifiers at the plant I work at that when turned off hold 100Vdc and 200Vdc depending on the rectifier. As of now it takes forever for the voltage to drop low enough for us to do any work. I have found bleeder resistors but I'm not sure what size we would need or if they go that big at all. Also not sure if we could just through in a battery or capacitor somewhere to store the excess energy. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the rectifiers, including the sizes of any capacitors? Additionally, do you have any occupational safety specifications that can be used to establish the necessary discharge time and safe voltage? Also: "capacitor somewhere to store the excess energy" -- the energy that you're trying to bleed off is almost certainly in a capacitor already.

Comment: I do not have a schematic. Which is not making things any easier. as far as safety standards go we will not touch the rectifier until it gets to around 50vDc which takes about 12ish hours.

Comment: Make and model? Photos?

Comment: Toshiba G8000 225Kva

Comment: Can you use the schematic tool and draw a diagram of what you think you have, as you understand it?

Comment: The G8000 manual indicates "The required discharge time for each UPS typeform is provided via a cabinet label and a CHARGE LED" -- does the label specify 12 hours? It's not clear if it's even allowable/safe to modify the unit to add a bleed resistor, but the manual seems to suggest against modifications.

Comment: Haven't looked at the label i was just told by our electrical guys that it takes them about 12 hours before they can touch it due to the voltage. We run everything off of a DCS so we can see the current voltage when its on/off. As far as modifications go im not sure if it is safe either.

Comment: Question: is the DC output disconnected from the battery bank when the G8000 is OFF?

Assuming yes, one solution is to attach a dynamic load to the DC output, and drain the energy off using that.  Bleed resistors will work also, but will always consume power if they are permanently attached.   You could safely use something like Ohmite HS10 10K J as a bleed resistor.  This will consume 4W all the time (assuming 200VDC).

Comment: Instead of modifying it internally maybe load its output down, e.g. with a device it is meant to power.

Comment: Chemical engineer and electricity problem? Using total 1MVA UPSes isn't  small-time business. Could this be based on bad agreements or a conflict with local union - a case where nobody is going to abandon achieved benefits, no matter how much it makes harm to production?